# Groups and Cent().

Tags: abstract-algebra

Having some issues with this problem. I understand the concept that is required for a group as it must have the following four properties:

1. $G$ is closed under the operation *
2. The operation * is associative on $G$
3. $G$ contains an identity element $e$
4. For each $f\in G$, there exists a $f^{-1} \in G$.

So lets say $(G,*)$ is a group, how do I prove that $(\mathrm{Cent}(G), *)$ is a group?

Comment: You tell me what Cent() is, you never defined it :) I would suspect it's the operation that takes a group, and returns its center; the set of elements that commute with everything in the group.

Comment: That's kinda what I thought too, but it didn't define it in the question. But that isn't really the problem. How do I prove those properties? Would I be right in saying that because the Cent of G is an element in G, then as we define (G,*) as a group, then an element of G is also a group?

Comment: $Cent(G)$ is probably the center of $G$ defined as $\{ g\in G \mid gh=hg \: \forall h\in G \} $.

Comment: I changed my question, realized I didn't ask what I wanted to. It was more about proving that (Cent(G), *) is a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant

> 1. $G$ is closed under the operation $*$
> 2. The operation $*$ is associative on G
> 3. $G$ contains an identity element $e$
> 4. For each $f \in G$, there exists  $f^{-1} \in G$ such that $f*f^{-1} = e =f^{-1}*f,$

you need to show that $Cent(G)$ (the usual notation is $Z(G)$, and I'm going to use that notation) satisfies each of these 4 properties.

So, you'll fix $z_1, z_2 \in Z(G)$, and verify that the product $z_1*z_2$ is also in $Z(G)$; that is, that $(z_1*z_2)*g = g*(z_1*z_2)$ for all $g \in G$; it commutes with everything in $G$. That will show property 1, that the product of two things in $Z(G)$ is also in $Z(G)$.

It will inherit property 2. from $G$. You should think about it and explain why; otherwise you'll need an arbitrary $z_3 \in Z(G)$ in addition, and show that $z_1*(z_2*z_3) = (z_1*z_2)*z_3$.

For 3. and 4., you'll need the same strategy from property 1., that certain key elements are in $Z(G)$: the identity, and the inverse of anything in $Z(G)$ (again by arguing that these things must commute with everything in $G$).

Comment: How do I verify the fact that z1∗z2 is also in Z(G)?

Comment: Because $z_1*z_2*g = z_1*g*z_2 = g*z_1*z_2$ by the definition of $Z(G)$.

Comment: Ah I remember now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cent(G) is defined to be the kernel of the homomorphism $f: G \to Aut(G)$. To check the kernel of a homomorphism is a subgroup simply check axioms 1 and 4.

$1) f(a)=1\ f(b) =1 \to f(a)f(b)=1 \to f(ab)=1$

$4) f (a)=1 \to f(a\ a^{-1})=1 \to f(a)f(a^{-1})=1 \to f(a^{-1})=1 $

Comment: Does that prove that (Cent(G),*) is a group though? That answer worries me as I have not seen anything like that before.

Comment: yes it does, normally you omit the group operation you are using.